# Netlogo how can I make something happen every 1000 ticks

Tags: netlogo

I have a model of tax evasion where the taxes should be payed each round, e.g. each 1000 ticks. As a placeholder, I have this code

```
ask traders with [ticks  = 1000 or ticks = 2000 or ticks = 3000];; Can this be set using a seed?
    [reset-parameters
       pay-taxes
       revise-behavior
       reset-turnover]
```

In SQL, I would have set done something like this:

FOR I IN 1..3000 LOOP
  ask traders with ticks = I*1000

Is there a similar function in Netlogo? Any other tips on how to make something happen every 1000 ticks?

Answer (score 7):

Your own solution will work, but is not optimal.

Since `ticks` is a global NetLogo reporter, and not a `traders` variable, the value returned by `ticks mod 1000 = 0` does not vary with each trader. It will either be `true` for all of them or `false` for all of them, so there is no use putting in in a `with` clause (where it will be re-evaluated for each trader).

It would be faster (and clearer) to just do:

```
if ticks mod 1000 = 0 [
  ask traders [
    do-something
  ]
]
```

Comment: That makes sense and was an easy fix! Thank you. N

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Seth. That's how it should have been in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Finally wrapped my head around a simple sollution:

```
 ask traders with [ticks mod 1000 = 0]
```

Comment: Is this solution actually the same as Seth's above (`if ticks mod 1000 = 0 []`)?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution to this problem that could even be tracked later on would to be a code like this

turtles-own [tradetime];;used to calculate time or can be changes to any variable

to go ;;or where ever
set tradetime tradetime + 1
ask traders [if (tradetime = 1000)[do-something]
end

or if you want to only have that value for traders then you can do this

turtles-own [tradetime]

to go 
ask traders [set tradetime tradetime + 1]
ask traders [if (tradetime = 1000)[do-something]
end
Hope this helped